# Replace cufon text inline with browser

Tags: browser, inline, cufon

My goal is simple : I have a page with cufon titles.

And I have a bookmarklet script to change all text on a page in lorem ipsum automatically.

But cufon text is not transformed.

Can I change cufon text with developer tool in chrome browser or other ?

I have tried with console to run a command like :

```
Cufon.reload();
```

or

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

But that doesn't work.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I  have found the solution :

First : replace alt attribute of the cufon tag.

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home"
```

to :

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Lorem"
```

Second execute in console :

```
Cufon.replace('.menu-item a');
```

in my case. (to be applicate for each element to replace)